# Having trouble with mouse pad working after installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: boot, uefi, 16.04, bios, mousepad

So I just received on old laptop from a friend and currently trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on the laptop.  Here are the specs of the laptop:

Brand: ASUS
Memory: 2.8 GiB
Processor: Intel Pentium(R) CPU P6200 @ 2.13 GHz
Graphics: Intel Ironlake Mobile
OS type: 64-bit
Disk: 1.5 GB

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using the same USB as I'm using right now on a desktop computer of mine I have, but put 16.04 LTS on it instead to go ahead and update. It came with Windows 7 pre-installed on the laptop and went ahead and wiped it out with Ubuntu.

When I tried to install, I've run into several problems:

1) For some reason the only way I can "use" the laptop now is if I boot the live USB in UEFI mode from the BIOS screen.  When I tried to boot up in a "non" UEFI mode for some reason it takes me to a GRUB screen which I don't know what to do from there.  When I install from the UEFI mode it gives me an option to "force the UEFI installation" which will essentially not let me able to boot up from the BIOS screen any more which I'm a little concerned with because that's the only way I've done it in the past.

2) When I do continue without forcing the UEFI installation it installs Ubuntu on there perfectly fine, but when I get to the home screen my mouse pad isn't recognized at all. Because of this, I can't enable my wifi because I can't click on it to choose which wifi I'm trying to connect too; which also doesn't allow me to install things through the terminal.

Here is what I get for my lsusb and lspci:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 154b:009f PNY
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b1e5 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM55 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
04:00.0 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 80)
04:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 80)
04:00.3 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller (rev 80)
04:00.4 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. xD Host Controller (rev 80)
04:00.5 Ethernet controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Please edit to include the output of `lsusb` and `lspci`

Comment: Ok I just did.  I put it in pastebin to save some space.  Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Do you have a USB mouse?

Comment: Yeah, I have a wireless USB mouse and when I tried it after booting up from my HDD it didn't work either.